# PHP: User Management, Data Access

Tags: php, database, user-management, data-access

i made a little web application in university and have some problems with data access.

There are 3 user accounts which can log in and all of them can create their own lectures afterwards.

Problem:
Each teacher should only see the lectures he created and not the ones the other two created. At the moment every teacher sees every lecture.

I don't know which code I should post here, but I am very thankful for any kind of help!

Thanks so much!

Edit: Thanks for your answer. I tried it the last few hours, but I have not idea what to to anymore.

That's my code where I save the lecture into the database. There seems to be a problem with the $_SESSION.

```
public function save(Vorlesung $vorlesung)
    {

        try {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('
              INSERT INTO vorlesung
                (name, login_dozent)
              VALUES
                (:name, '$_SESSION[dozent]')
            ');
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $vorlesung->name);
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo("Fehler! Bitten wenden Sie sich an den Administrator...<br>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>");
            die();
        }
        return $vorlesung;
    }
```

That's my login code:

```
<?php
require_once("Mapper/DozentManager.php");
require_once("Mapper/Dozent.php");

$login = htmlspecialchars($_POST["login"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

if (!empty($login) && !empty($password)) {
    $DozentManager = new DozentManager();
    $dozent = $DozentManager->findByLogin($login, $password);
    if ($dozent==null) {
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    } else {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION ['dozent'] = $dozent;
        $_SESSION ['login'] = "1";
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen!<br/>";
}
```

Comment: First of all: very welcome to stackoverflow! This seems to be your homework - and people here don't like to do your stuff.

Comment: Welcome to SO: to help us help you, what have you tried? we can only give extremely general solutions to the current question which may not be helpful to you at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very precise, without example of code...
So let's be general :
you store into your database :
- teachers (each of them may have a unique login or id)
- lectures : each of them should include a data to identify your teacher : its unique login or id.

Then you will be able to filter your lectures using the currently connected teacher you should have store as a session value for example.

On login script :

- check if the teacher is in database using its login + password and gets its unique login or id. Then store it into a session value :

$_SESSION['teacher'] = $the_teacher_id

- when you create a lecture, store the teacher id into the database, with the other data of the lecture :
  INSERT INTO lectures (teacher, other_lecture_data) VALUES ('$_SESSION[teacher]', $other_lecture_data_value);
- when you list all available lectures, filter them using the currently connected teacher unique login or id :

SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE teacher = '$_SESSION[teacher]';

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In theory that sounds great, but I still have some problems with my code. I edited my answer above. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your lecture table should look like this:

```
id | lecture_name | teacher_id
------------------------------
1  | lecture 1    | 1
2  | lecutre 2    | 2
```

Your query should look like this:

```
select * from lecture where teacher_id = 1; // or another teacher id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still don't know how I manage to get the teacher_id into the lectures table.